# Understanding log_prob for Normal distribution in pytorch

Tags: reinforcement-learning, pytorch, probability-distribution

I'm currently trying to solve Pendulum-v0 from the openAi gym environment which has a continuous action space. As a result, I need to use a Normal Distribution to sample my actions. What I don't understand is the dimension of the log_prob when using it :

```
import torch
from torch.distributions import Normal 

means = torch.tensor([[0.0538],
        [0.0651]])
stds = torch.tensor([[0.7865],
        [0.7792]])

dist = Normal(means, stds)
a = torch.tensor([1.2,3.4])
d = dist.log_prob(a)
print(d.size())
```

I was expecting a tensor of size 2 (one log_prob for each actions) but it output a tensor of size(2,2).

However, when using a Categorical distribution for discrete environment the log_prob has the expected size:

```
logits = torch.tensor([[-0.0657, -0.0949],
        [-0.0586, -0.1007]])

dist = Categorical(logits = logits)
a = torch.tensor([1, 1])
print(dist.log_prob(a).size())
```

give me a tensor a size(2).

Why is the log_prob for Normal distribution of a different size ?

Comment: I suggest you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i.e. a simple program that can be executed so that we can verify the behavior you're describing, rather than a screenshot of the program!

Comment: I edited my question with the code

Comment: The PyTorch documentation is very poor, so I completely understand you. Anyway, this documentation page [https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/distributions.html) says that the PyTorch distribution module follows the same design as TensorFlow Probability. If that's really the case, then you may try having a look at the documentation of TFP. I am currently using TFP and I may be able to answer this question, but later. Ping me later, if you don't receive an answer meanwhile.

Comment: Okay thank you for your time

Answer (score 7):

If one takes a look in the [source code](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/distributions/normal.html#Normal.log_prob) of **torch.distributions.Normal** and finds the definition of the log_prob(value) function, one can see that the main part of the calculation is:

```
return -((value - self.loc) ** 2) / (2 * var) - some other part
```

where **value** is a variable containing values for which you want to calculate the log probability (in your case, **a**), **self.loc** is the mean of the distribution (in you case, **means**) and **var** is the variance, that is, the square of the standard deviation (in your case, **stds****2). One can see that this is indeed the logarithm of the probability density function of the [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution), minus some constants and logarithm of the standard deviation that I don't write above.

In the first example, you define **means** and **stds** to be column vectors, while the **values** to be a row vector

```
means = torch.tensor([[0.0538],
    [0.0651]])
stds = torch.tensor([[0.7865],
    [0.7792]])
a = torch.tensor([1.2,3.4])
```

But subtracting a row vector from a column vector, that the code does in **value - self.loc** in Python gives a matrix (try!), thus the result you obtain is a value of log_prob for each of your two defined distribution and for each of the variables in **a**.

If you want to obtain a log_prob without the cross terms, then define the variables consistently, i.e., either

```
means = torch.tensor([[0.0538],
    [0.0651]])
stds = torch.tensor([[0.7865],
    [0.7792]])
a = torch.tensor([[1.2],[3.4]])
```

or

```
means = torch.tensor([0.0538,
    0.0651])
stds = torch.tensor([0.7865,
    0.7792])
a = torch.tensor([1.2,3.4])
```

This is how you do in your second example, which is why you obtain the result you expected.